# Install newer version of grunt

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

I submit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479356/npm-not-install-underscore-packages)‌ in stackoverflow, A person answered 
Now I want to install a newer version of grunt?

Comment: Dear downvoter: this is more complex than you thought, and is actually a good question, despite being localized. Alas, that close reason was removed, as the SO gods have decreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that patch isn't in a release that has been pushed to npm yet. So you need to grab the master version from github.

```
npm uninstall grunt
npm install https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/archive/master.tar.gz
```

Or the shorter version as mentioned in the comments:

```
npm install gruntjs/grunt
```

Comment: I dont have any grunt version

Comment: You can do: `npm i gruntjs/grunt` instead and npm will install from the master branch on github.